# Clarkeash/Doorman Composer post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1 Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

i want install the package clarkeash/doorman, for generate url invitation code, but i have this error when i execute the composer require. And i use php artisan clear and other error but given the same. My version of laravel is 7.13.0

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want told me of other package to use, you can said, but i need solution this problem, please help.

Comment: Please never share code or error messages in images - they are pure text and can be shared best as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the first time that you see this error?

Is config variable set on `config/doorman.php`?

If you don't see this file you can create it using

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=doorman-config`

and you neet to set `invite_model` on this file

Comment: thanks to anwser @Tian Ming, i send this issiue to owner of package and he told me, this package, It is not intended for windows, he will fix this problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the solution. btw did you try above? I didn't even try that :) Thank you for accepting my answer as your solution

Comment: Not because the package was made for free operating system, :/ and the routes or path is to linux, not to windows :/, thanks to answer, because,if i will had the same problem, i can fix.